# Windows XP cant join Server 2008 Domain

Tags: active-directory

I've setup a new Server 2008 box with a new domain.  I've done all my testing with a Windows 7 laptop which is being deployed with the network.  It joined the domain fine, and worked as expected.

Now for the deploy, I've got to join a couple of XP boxes to the domain, but when joining, they come up with `A domain controller for the domain could not be contacted`, details below:

> DNS was successfully queried for the
>   service location (SRV) resource record
>   used to locate a domain controller for
>   domain acron.local:
>
> The query was for the SRV record for
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.acron.local
>
> The following domain controllers were
>   identified by the query:
>
> svpdc.acron.local
>
> Common causes of this error include:
>
> - Host (A) records that map the name of the domain controller to its IP
>     addresses are missing or contain
>     incorrect addresses.
> - Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or
>     are not running

All those records and correct and are resolving correctly from the XP clients, with pings and lookups.

The Win 7 laptop is still working fine, I've even removed and rejoined it to the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is weird. How about...

On the XP machine;

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset log
shutdown -r -t 0
```

Comment: That appears to have worked.  For the first one at least, trying the rest now.

Answer (score 0):

Are the network connections of the XP computers properly configured? Joining a domain have some requirements (like a proper network mask, and maybe using the domain as gateway and primary DNS).