# Why does my XP client try to join a domain with the pre-windows 2000 domain name?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp

I do not have problems with any other clients (Win 7 Pro).  But sometimes I have an XP SP3 client that will not join the domain.  The reason is because it is looking for the pre-Windows 2000 domain name.

So I have my "real" domain name as contoso.com and my pre-win name is contoso (not real names obviously).

The reason this fails is because I upgraded my AD to 2008 R2.  There are no more records in _ldap for the old domain "short name."  When I do a query with nslookup, set q=srv, I do not get the old pre-win 2k domain name, only the current one that I upgraded.

This makes sense, and I understand why the XP client doesn't find the old domain pre-win name.  That old pre-win2k name is no longer in DNS.

To be clear.  I did not change domain names.  I had a Windows 2000 SP4 domain.  I upgraded my AD to 2008 R2.  The pre-win2k is still listed.  To complicate it, I have a remaining Win2k DC and my domain functional level is stuck at 2000 native for the moment.

**I was able to finally join my domain by forcing the NIC to use NetBIOS names, but I am concerned.  I tried all I could to remove any domain name caching on the XP client.**

Is something wrong with my XP client or my domain?  The computer used to be connected to the domain.  I removed it.  Removed it from the domain, etc.  Later tried to rejoin then the above.

It is similar but not completely to this:

[Windows XP cant join Server 2008 Domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/200588/windows-xp-cant-join-server-2008-domain)

Thanks.

edit:  I have no WINS servers.  In DNS for each DNS server, I unchecked WINS.  I do not have WINS in the client either.

Comment: no wins servers correct?

Comment: @tonyroth Correct.  No WINS.

Comment: so if you do a ping contoso.com then and nslookup contoso.com does it return the same result?

Comment: @tonyroth I can ping my domain controllers and the suffix along.  I can do nslookup for both.  I found several things when I searched correctly with "xp cannot join 2008 domain."  Don't know what it was.  I am leaning towards the machine though, the client, not the domain.

Comment: don't ping the the controllers "ping contoso.com" then do an "nslookup contoso.com" are the results the same?  Also are there any hosts files involved?

Comment: @tonyroth I edited it.  Yes.  I pinged the domain.  No host files.  No lmhosts either.